# Ida - what is Parse C header file

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

In ida File->Load file there is option Parse C header file, I want to understand that .

If I have the headers file that compiled with my binary I can attach and then see all the structures/function name in ida Psudocode /disassembly  ??

How is that works how Ida can links the struct/class from header to binary?

Comment: 1. Depends on the binary 2. It follows function signatures, most of the time we've to set data type manually.

Answer (score 3):

it allows to load type definitions into IDA. I.e. define IDA structures by parsing C header file, so that you don't have to define your structures manually.